# Sum of squared degrees in tripartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have come across a graph-theoretic problem where it would be nice to bound the "sum of squared degrees", in the following sense. We have a graph $G$ with vertex set $[n]$ and let $d(G) = \sum_{i=1}^n \deg(i)^2$.

Has this parameter been studied before, perhaps in some special cases?
I would appreciate any pointers to the literature, especially for cases in which the order of $d(G)$ is significantly less than $n^3$. In particular, is this true when $G$ is tripartite and the edge set of $G$ is a union of disjoint triangles?

**Edit.** Based on the comments below, it seems that the problem reduces to the following. Suppose that a graph $G$ is such that its
edge set is a union of triangles (no two triangles share an edge but they may share a vertex). Can one bound the number of cherries (ordered triples $(u,v,w)$ such
that $v$ is adjacent to both $u$ and $w$), possibly by $O(n^2)$? I apologise if this is somewhat trivial, I cannot see the argument straightaway.

**Edit 2.** This should really go in a comment to the answer by Seva, but I cannot figure out how to attach an image. I believe this is a counterexample, as the edge set is the union of four edge-disjoint triangles, but vertices $0$ and $3$ are the endvertices of two distinct cherries.

[image]

Comment: The sum of squares of the degrees is, essentially, the number of "cherries" (triples of vertices $(u,v,w)$ with $v$ adjacent to both $u$ and $w$). The rest depends on exactly what do you want to prove.

Comment: @Seva In the case where the edge set is a union of disjoint triangles, the number of cherries is exactly the number of edges. Does this mean that $d(G)$ is roughly the number of edges?

Comment: The sum of squares is $N+2e$, where $N$ is the number of cherries and $e$ is the number of edges of the graph. Thus, if the graph is the union of edge-disjoint triangles, then the sum is precisely equal to $3e$.

Comment: In this count, every triple $(u,v,w)$ gives raise to *two* cherries. (That is, the cherries are oriented.) If we let $M$ denote the number of nonoriented cherries, then the sum of the squares is $2M+2e$, which for a union of triangles gives $4e$ for the sum of the squares.

Comment: @Seva Thanks for this calculation! It is quite surprising to me that the sum of the squares is on the same order as the number of edges in my tripartite graph because it raises an apparent contradiction. I will work it out precisely to see what is going on.

Comment: Okay, what went wrong was my statement that if the edge set of the graph is a union of disjoint triangles, then the number of cherries is the number of edges. This is wrong because the triangles may share vertices (but not edges).

Comment: Do you mean that no two triangles in your graph share a common edge? If so, $O(n^2)$ is easy.

Comment: @Seva Yes, the graph is a union of triangles that possibly share vertices but not edges.

Comment: It is not the same as no two triangles sharing an edge!

Comment: @Seva Yes, sorry that I am not being very clear. I do actually mean to say that no two triangles in the graph share an edge. Furthermore, one can assume that every edge is in a triangle. If you have an answer, I would be happy to accept it, since my question is too general to really be interesting but at least for this special case we could get a bound.

Comment: Your sum is $o(n^3)$, and you cannot do better than, say, $n^3e^{-c\sqrt{\ln n}}$; google for the "diamond-free lemma".